# How can I get the new position and size of a UIElement after performing a RenderTransform (Scale & Translate)?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am performing scaling, translation and rotation on an image using RenderTransform. Transformations are not done using mouse events, rather, the user will click a button and then the image will scale/translate/rotate on a fixed value.

My problem is I want to determine the new position/size of the image each time a scaling, translation or rotation is performed. So I added Changed events on the code-behind. The question is how do you get the new position/size?

Please take a look at what I've done so far:

**XAML:**

```
<Border x:Name="mainImageBorderCtrl" ClipToBounds="True">
     <Grid x:Name="imageGridCtrl">
          <Grid.RenderTransform>
               <TranslateTransform Changed="TranslateTransform_Changed"/>
          </Grid.RenderTransform>
          <Image x:Name="mainImageCtrl" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5" Source="{Binding Image}">
               <Image.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                         <ScaleTransform Changed="ScaleTransform_Changed"/>
                         <RotateTransform />
                    </TransformGroup>
               </Image.RenderTransform>
          </Image>
     </Grid>
</Border>
```

Please note that I separated TranslateTransform from ScaleTransform and RotateTransform so that the orientation won't be affected.

The following are the 2 changed events. In here, I expect to get the new position/size every time a scale or a translate has occurred. But the bounds values do not change.

**Code-behind**

```
private Rect bounds;

private void TranslateTransform_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     bounds = imageGridCtrl.TransformToAncestor(mainImageBorderCtrl).TransformBounds(new Rect(imageGridCtrl.RenderSize));
}

private void ScaleTransform_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     bounds = imageGridCtrl.TransformToAncestor(mainImageBorderCtrl).TransformBounds(new Rect(imageGridCtrl.RenderSize));
}
```

**EDIT**: My goal here is to restrict the translation(panning) of the Image inside the Border control, that's why I need to get the bounds of the Image after each transformation, whatever the transformation is, so that I can check whether the bounds of the Image exceeds the Border.

Comment: `ScaleTransform` won't affect the bounds since bound is same. It's just content is scaled. Whereas `TranslateTransform` does works for me, it shows `Left` and `Top` to be updated on new bounds. Aren't you observing the same behaviour for TranslateTransform?

Comment: Ah yes. The ScaleTransform is my problem. My goal here is to restrict the translation (panning) of the image inside the Border control. That's why I need to know the bounds of the Image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TranslateTransform` is generating correct bounds. However, for `ScaleTransform` you are getting bounds on control `imageGridCtrl` but the transform is added as child of control `mainImageCtrl`.

So you should **use `mainImageCtrl` in place of `imageGridCtrl` to get correct bounds**:

```
bounds = mainImageCtrl.TransformToAncestor(mainImageBorderCtrl)
                      .TransformBounds(new Rect(mainImageCtrl.RenderSize));
```

Comment: Surprisingly, I just realized this a while ago when I am debugging. :D Thank you for the clarification and help. This I will vote as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

The transform change events fire too early. You should hook up to `LayoutUpdated` event of the image control. Then try:

```
mainImageCtrl.TransformToAncestor(mainImageBorderCtrl)
    .TransformBounds(new Rect(mainImageCtrl.RenderSize))
```

Comment: The problem is not with the Changed events but on the getting of the bounds. The position/size of the bounds are always the same as the original position/size no matter how many times you apply rendertransform.